# Displaying latest news and upcoming events on the front page of Moodle site

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle and I am working to develop a theme for moodle site. I have to show three boxes next to other on the front page. one box will show upcoming events and other will show latest news. I have noticed the boxes of latest news and upcoming events are displaying correctly in inner pages but I don't know how to display these boxes on the front page. I am using moodle 2.3.3. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your code into the "summary" of the frontpage, using Moodle's HTML editor.

If you're comfortable with php and html, you should add your boxes directly into the frontpage.php from your Moodle theme (/theme/*your_current_theme*/layout/frontpage.php).

Edit your frontpage.php, it may looks like this :

```
<!-- start of moodle content -->
        <div id="page-content">
            <div id="region-main-box">
                <div id="region-post-box">

                    <!-- main mandatory content of the moodle page  -->
                    <div id="region-main-wrap">
                        <div id="region-main">
                            <div class="region-content">
                                <?php echo $OUTPUT->main_content() ?>

                                HERE IS THE PLACE TO ADD BOXES.

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of main mandatory content of the moodle page -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to add three boxes horizontally and this code will add boxes vertically i think and I am unable to handle these boxes through css.

Comment: You have to play with css floats, using <div>. Otherwise, if you still have issues with css, you can build a html table.